# Let $p_k$ be the $k$th prime, can it be shown for $p \ge 5$, that there is not always a twin prime between $p_k^2$ and $p_{k+1}^2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

For any primorial $p_k \ge 3$, $p_k\#$, there are $$\prod_{2\le{i}\le{k}} (p_i-2)$$ distinct instances of $x,x+2$ that are relatively prime to $p_k\#$.

If any of these pairs are less than $p_{k+1}^2$, then they are necessarily twin primes.

For the heck of it, I wrote a tiny app that checks all the primes up to 191,137 and in each case there was at least one twin prime between $p_k^2$ and $p_{k+1}^2$.

Can it be proven that this eventually fails?  Are there two consecutive primes $p_m, p_{m+1}$ such that if $p_i$ is a prime and $p_m^2 < p_i < p_{m+1}^2$, then $p_i,p_{i+1}$ are not a twin primes.

Comment: The question in your title and the last sentence of the description aren't equivalent.

Comment: @Dennis, could you explain.  Here's my view why they are equivalent.  There is not always a twin prime between $p_k^2$ and $p_{k+1}^2$ iff there exists two consecutive primes $p_m,p_{m+1}$ such that any prime $p_i$ that is in between $p_m^2$ and $p_{m+1}^2$ is not a twin prime.

Comment: Ah, just reread it. For some reason, I thought the second statement was only looking for one prime that isn't the smaller of a set of twin primes. Ignore me.

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718774/a-necklace-problem-related-to-the-modulo-function

Comment: let $t(n)$ denote the $n$ th triangular number.
Then we have :
Between $t(a)-1$ and $t(a+1)+1$ always exists at least $1$ prime.
Between $t(a)-1$ and $t(a+3)+1$ always exists at least $1$ prime twin.
Between $t(a)-1$ and $t(a+2k+1)+1$ always exists at least $1$ prime constellation of the form $(p,...,p+2k)$.
( tommy's conjecture )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a small interval, so suppose you have twin primes ($p_k+2=p_{k+1}$). Then the gap is roughly $4\sqrt{x}$ with numbers around $x$. Heuristics suggest that, on average, such an interval would contain about
$$
\frac{8C_2\sqrt{x}}{\log^2 x}
$$
twin primes, where $C_2\approx0.6601618158$ is the twin prime constant. If we treat the primes as being Poisson distributed, the chance that no primes would be found in the interval is
$$
\exp\left(-\frac{8C_2\sqrt{x}}{\log^2 x}\right)
$$

For example, if $x=191137^2$ (using your number) then the chance is about 1 in $10^{741}$. The probabilities drop off rapidly from there, so probably you can find a pair of twin primes in any such interval.

Comment: Hello Charles, I want to learn such heuristic methods. Where can I learn probabilistic estimation techniques for number theory? Can you suggest a book for a beginner (or video lectures)? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know of any videos. You could try Hardy & Wright's textbook, but you may need a gentler introduction first depending on your level of knowledge.

Comment: @Isomorphism: Basically, you just assume that a random integer n is a prime with probability 1 / ln n. If p is a prime, then the probability that p+2 is prime is _slightly_ different, because you know that p+2 is odd (unless p=2), but a bit more likely to be divisible by 3, 5, 7, 11 etc. than a random number. And then you start calculating based on that.