# At what point does the number twin prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ stop increasing in count?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

This question was so well stated by someone else that I am quoting [their words](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19932/48606) here:

> Let $a(n)$ be the number of pairs of twin primes between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$. Of course,
>   if the twin primes conjecture is false then $a(n)$ is zero for large $n$. But is anything
>   known or conjectured about the behaviour of $a(n)$ as $n→∞$?
>
> For example, is it known or conjectured whether $a(n)$ is bounded? Or whether it tends to
>   infinity?

Here's the work that I did up to now:

I noticed that there are always twin primes between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ except for $n \in \left\{9,19,26,27,30,34,39,49,53,77,122\right\}$.

For $n >1330, a(n)$ fluctuates but continues to reach higher numbers and for $n>1330$ does not fall below $\left\lfloor\dfrac{\text{highest found so far}}{3}\right\rfloor$ for any $n$ that I checked.

For example:

- For $1000 \le n \le 2000$, $7 \le a(n) \le 35$
- For $4000 \le n \le 5000$, $17 \le a(n) \le 60$
- For $9000 \le n \le 10,000$, $30 \le a(n) \le 99$
- For $59,000 \le n \le 60,000$, $125 \le a(n) \le 379$

I suspect $a(n)$ must stop reaching higher numbers at some point because the sum of the reciprocals of twin primes is convergent.  Does anyone know at what point it stops?   Can anyone provide references to methods of analysis that can be used to determine this point.

In an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/538365/48606) to a similar question, the following analysis was given:

> Suppose you have twin primes ($p_k+2=p_{k+1}$). Then the gap is
>   roughly $4\sqrt{x}$ with numbers around $x$. Heuristics suggest that,
>   on average, such an interval would contain about
>
> $\frac{8C_2\sqrt{x}}{\log^2 x}$
>   twin primes
>
> where $C_2\approx0.6601618158$ is the twin prime constant.
>
> If we treat the
>   primes as being Poisson distributed, the chance that no primes would be found in the
>   interval is:
>
> $\exp\left(-\frac{8C_2\sqrt{x}}{\log^2 x}\right)$

I am not clear on the details of this analysis.  Can it be used to determine the point where $a(n)$ stops increasing.

---

Edit:  Removed the term "pattern" from the question and removed the terms "maximum" and "minimum" which were used incorrectly.  I reworded the question to focus on my main point.

---

Edit 2: I changed "number" to "frequency" based on a comment which is more accurate and changed my question to "at what point" as suggested by a comment.  Thanks to everyone for all the comments.

Comment: Even the existence of infinitely many twin primes is not proved yet. It is open problem since many years ago. For more, read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime

Comment: Yes, that was why I was surprised that the max and min are consistently increasing.  I did not expect to find this result.

Comment: Not directly related but could give you ideas: I posted a similar test regarding twin primes, but in my case the pivot points were the position of the twin primes. In other words, how many twin primes are around a twin prime pair within a radius equal to the value of the even number betwen the twin primes. Graphs included (sorry added in the next comment)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005852/test-total-number-of-twin-primes-in-the-vicinity-of-twin-primes-how-can-i-calc

Comment: Thanks for the link.  More stuff to think about.  :-)

Comment: `Does this pattern continue for as far as we know?` - What pattern?

Comment: "Q.: What pattern? A.: I don't know." Reads like the epitome of NARQ to me.

Comment: Thanks to Did. :-) I had misunderstood what barak manos was saying.  Sorry, @barak manos.  The pattern, as I understand it, is that the minimum and maximum number of twin primes found between successive squares is continually increasing.  For $1000 \le x \le 2000$, the maximum found is $35$ and the minimum found is $11$.  For $2000 \le x \le 3000$, the maximum found is $46$ and the minimum found is $15$.  That's the pattern that I was seeing.

Comment: So you understood what I was saying thanks to @Did's comment??? That's funny, because I didn't really understand that comment myself. In any case, I wouldn't quite call it "a pattern". Although increasing, it's more of a "randomly-looking" sequence... But I guess it's a matter of your definition of the word "pattern" (it sure ain't my definition).

Comment: I see  your point.  I have misused the word "pattern".  I'll edit my question to remove the term.  Thanks very much.  I believe that Did was saying that my comment sounds like an automated response rather than a thinking person.  That was the closest I could find to [NARQ](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/NARQ) as an acronym.

Comment: "I know that the twin prime conjecture is an open problem. I was interested in understanding if this trend of increasing frequency of twin primes between successive squares stops at some point." You probably use "frequency" for "number" but anyway, do you realize that if the twin primes conjecture is false (in the sense that there would be a finite number of twin primes) then the number of twin primes between successive squares *cannot* increase forever? Hence, do you realize that your question, even in its revised version, is nothing less than a *refinement* of the twin primes conjecture?

Comment: "There, you are not right." Eeeeh? Sorry, how was I not right? Please read *carefully* what I wrote.

Comment: @Did, it is possible that I misunderstood your point.  I tried to read it *carefully*. Let me try to put my point more clearly.  I expected the number of twin primes between successive squares to eventually start decreasing since the sum of the reciprocals of twin primes is convergent.  I am trying to figure out at what point that occurs.  So, to be clear, I am not interested in proving or disproving the twin prime conjecture.  I am interested in understanding the implication of Brun's constant.  I hope that clears up my point.

Comment: "I am trying to figure out at what point that occurs." Does this appear anywhere in the question? (As an aside, let me note that, in mathematical circles (in contrast with everyday life, no to mention politics...), to say that somebody is "not right" has a precise and strong meaning, and that one should be able to substantiate such assertions when one makes them. Obviously, in the present case you are not. Be aware that this can have consequences on the way people take what you say afterwards.)

Comment: Thanks, Did!  I'll delete the comment.  I apologize for misusing the word "not right".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of twin-primes between successive squares should increase. There will be some fluctuations yet there will be a very clear upwards trend.

Of course, this is conjecturally as no one knows if there are infinitely many twin-primes, so the count  theoretically could be $0$ from some point on, but this is very unlikely.

In more detail: it is expected that the number of twin-prime pairs up to $x$ is asymptotically 
$$2C_2 \frac{x}{(\log x)^2}$$
where $C_2$ is the so-called twin-prime constant which is about $0.66$. 
This can be put differently as saying that a number of size about $x$, is twin-prime (say, the smaller of a pair for definiteness) with "probability" about
$$ \frac{2C_2}{(\log x)^2}.$$
Still differently an interval $[x, x+y]$ should contain 
$$ \frac{2C_2y}{(\log (x +y))^2}$$
twin-prime numbers *if* the $y$ is not too small relative to $x$; but it being of size $x^{\theta}$ for some positive $\theta$ should suffice. Again, this is of course conjecturally; it is not even known for the primes if there is prime in every interval $[x,x+\sqrt{x}]$ (this is Legendre's conjecture, though one is close).

So what does this tell us about the question: between $N^2$ and $(N+ 1)^2 = N^2 + 2N + 1$ we thus expect about 
$$\frac{2C_2 2N}{(\log (N+1)^2)^2}$$
which reduces to about 
$$\frac{C_2 N}{(\log N)^2}$$ 
which grows as $N$ grows.

This does not match the data you give too well, but first the numbers considered are small in that context and you only mention the maximum while what I give should be the typical/average value.